# I tried adding PhoneNumberTextfield but it's not showing up

Tags: swift, uikit

Currently, I tried to add the PhoneNumberTextField but it's not showing up I'm not sure why

```
import UIKit
import PhoneNumberKit

class EnterPhoneNumberViewController: UIViewController {
    private let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Enter your phone number"
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    private let phoneNumberTextField: PhoneNumberTextField = {
        let phoneNumberTextField = PhoneNumberTextField()
        return phoneNumberTextField
    }()

    private let bottomLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Remember never signup"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    private let bottomLabel2: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "with another person's phone number"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    private let nextButton: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 114/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        view.addSubview(bottomLabel)
        view.addSubview(bottomLabel2)
        view.addSubview(phoneNumberTextField)
        view.addSubview(nextButton)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            titleLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            
            phoneNumberTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor),
            phoneNumberTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            phoneNumberTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            
            bottomLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 100),
            bottomLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            
            bottomLabel2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLabel.bottomAnchor),
            bottomLabel2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            
            nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            nextButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
            nextButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20),
            nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            nextButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

[image]

It seems like the `titleLabel` is not even showing up, but if I remove the `phoneNumberTextField` it would show up

Example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us what class `PhoneNumberTextField` is, but...

For all of your other UI elements, you are setting `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Looks like you missed it for that element:

```
private let phoneNumberTextField: PhoneNumberTextField = {
    let phoneNumberTextField = PhoneNumberTextField()

    // add this
    phoneNumberTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return phoneNumberTextField
}()
```